# Need to pass parameter dynamically for Excel generation

Tags: java, resultset

I am having a select query, which generate dynamically according to the number of fields that the user selects from multiple select box.

```
 while (rs.next()) {
 data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[] {rs.getString(1),      rs.getString(2)});
 i++; 
 }
```

I have created query dynamically.
Now i need to pick the values from DB using `rs.getString()`.

Above I have given two fields manually. but in my case number fields may vary according to user selection.
so something like List reference i have to put instead of `rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2).`
 can any one give suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1: please form your select query with selective columns based on user selection.
if the user selects col1, col2, please form query like select col1, col2 from table.

Step2: Use the ResultSetMetaData api method getColumnCount() to know the no of columns available in resultset

Step3: Based on Step2, use getXXXMethod(columnIndex) to retrieve the values.

Example:
int count = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

```
while (rs.next())
{
String[] colValues = new String()[count];
for(int i=0; i<count;i++)
{
colValues[i] = rs.getString(i);
}
System.out.println("The current result set values are :"+colValues);
}
```

Comment: I done step 1,step 2, actually the count for step 2 will get at the time of step 1. inside while loop data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[] {rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)}); so instead of rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2) need to put any list variable or??